# How does Mathematica StackExchange support itself?

Tags: discussion

I don't remember ever seeing a "help support ..." like I do on Wikipedia.

Comment: As in, financially? The community is completely voluntary except for some occasional light-touch stuff from the Stack Exchange people. Any money generated by ads etc goes to the Stack Exchange people and presumably is enough to keep the lights on and the servers running.

Comment: @CarlLange I'm not at all sure that we contribute positively to the Stack Exchange bottom-line, but I think the cost of supporting another SE site once they already have like ServerFault or Math.SE or some of the big ones is probably quite small. We have a small memory footprint and are volunteer operated for the most part. Also we don't generate controversy like Interpersonal Relationships or whichever site that was...